# Entity Framework 4.1 Type and Table splitting

Tags: entity-framework, mapping, code-first

I have folowing tables structure in my DB:

**Indication**

- Id
- Type
- InstanceName
- StringValue
- IntValue

and i have this class structure

```
abstract class Indication  
{
    public int Id { get; set; }  
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public string InstanceName { get; set; }
}

class StringIndication : Indication  
{
    public string Value { get; set;}
}

class IntIndication : Indication  
{
    public intValue { get; set;}
}
```

i want to map my table to this structure depends on Type property. 
So, that was easy:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Indication>()
    .Map<IntIndication>(m => m.Requires("Type").HasValue(1))
    .Map<StringIndication>(m => m.Requires("Type").HasValue(2));
modelBuilder.Entity<IntIndication>().Property(c => c.Value).HasColumnName("IntValue");
modelBuilder.Entity<StringIndication>().Property(c => c.Value).HasColumnName("StringValue");
```

It worked fine, but now i want to do one more thing. I want to have dictionary of InstanceName's.
So, i create another table

**Instance**

- Id
- Name

,changed InstanceName in Indication table to InstanceId.

But i don't want lookup property like

```
public Instance Instance {get;set;}
```

in my Indication table.
Instead i want to keep

```
    public string InstanceName { get; set; }
```

and add additional

```
    public id InstanceId { get; set; }
```

so, how should i change my mapping to do this work?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would have your answer:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj715646.aspx 
it covers the EF Designer - Map an Entity to Multiple Tables (Entity Splitting)